# Mailto on IE 9 - Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Tags: internet-explorer-9, intranet, mailto

I am having some issues with the mailto on IE 9. The problem is that after pressing on the mailto link, IE 9 tries to open the URL with the mail address and after some seconds I get a page redirect and the outlook (which is the program associated to the mailto protocol) finally opens.

For example: I click on the mailto link -> A new tab opens with this address -> "mailto:diego@maradona.com" and the page displays the "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error. Then outlook opens fine.

Facts:

- If I try to open a mailto from the internet, it works perfect, the problem is only with intranet site
- If I open the mailto from a local html (not on IIS), it works perfect
- I can open the mailto fine on IE 7 and 8

---

I found a "dirty" solution to this problem, I have added a hidden Iframe inside the page and a function to change the src attribute as needed.

```
function doMailto(mailto) {
        document.getElementById("iframe").src = "mailto:" + mailto;
    }
```

Comment: It is probably the configuration in IIS for handling the mailto-type (MIME?)

Comment: @Michael9000 IIS is not responsible for understanding what to do with the protocol*. for instance the `tel:` link is handled by your browser, no request is sent to the server. *while I know IIS handles the protocol down range, it's not here.

Comment: Your dirty solution is the only way I've found around this issue, thanks.